# Comparing scikit learn clusterings using a decision tree

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I am doing a project for a class where I take some data from LIBSVM and run it through 2 different clustering algorithms. I have my kmeans  generating 8 clusters, while my agglomerative is grouping them into 3 clusters.

Now, I'm trying to tell if the cluster labels generated by my kmeans can be used to predict the cluster labels generated by my agglomerative clustering, e.g. do all the instances in cluster #6 map to cluster#1 from the agg clustering.

My professor has advised the use of a decision tree classifier but I'm not quite sure how to do this. I know I would take the agg clustering labels as the class labels and then input my data into it and see how it was classified. This is where my questions lie and I have several:

1) What does the scikit learn decision tree classifier output? Is it the list of probabilities which each instance might be classified as? Or does it explicitly classify each instance?

2) After I input my data and each instance has been classified into one of the 3 clusters generated by Agg, how do I go in and find out which clustering it belonged to from kmeans?

3) Is there a better way to do this? All we need to do is "Compare the clusters produced by the different methods in a quantitative way" so we don't need to necessarily use decision tree classifiers, but I'm not sure what another good way would be. I've considered the rand and adjusted rand index but those don't seem to be what I'm looking for

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Let me answer 3) first.
YES! sklearn.metrics.cluster [See the documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/clustering.html#clustering-evaluation). This is written with the viewpoint of a "true reference" but that is not really necessary, Adjusted Rand Index and Normalized Mutual Information are great for comparing how similar two clusterings are, and each will produce a meaningful number.

1) either. `predict` give classes, `predict_proba` gives probabilities.

2) I don't understand the question.

Comment: Thanks!  Would I have to make my agglomerative clustering produce 8 clusters? I feel like mapping from 8 to 3 clusters would throw off the evaluation

Comment: ARI etc. can handle different numbers of clusters.